# Issue while using GDB to find the reason of a segmentationf fault

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

I've been trying to use GDB to debug a palindrome recognizing program. I entered into gdb and ran it by doing a command:

```
run aca
```

It then printed out

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 1 (LWP 1)]
0x00010e38 in findEnd ()
```

So I'm assuming there's something wrong in my `findEnd()`.

I then did:

```
bt
```

and it printed out

```
0x00010e38 in findEnd ()
```

Is there any way I can figure out what line exactly in findEnd is causing this seg fault error? I'm assuming that the 38 at the end of the line doesn't indicate line number, does it?

Please let me know if I need to add more details!

Comment: while compiling , use the `-g` flag. It will give out more information, including the line number and erroneous instruction.

Comment: 38 is part of the address not the line number that you are hoping for.  You can set a break point at `findEnd()` and step through it.

Comment: Sourav: Make this into an answer, so question can be closed.

Comment: So I would use the -g flag when doing something like :

gdb program -g

?

Comment: No. You use the `-g` flag when compiling. For example, `g++ -g whatever.cpp`. You can pass a level to the flag: `g2`, `g3`. Check the docs for more info.

Comment: `-g` tells gcc to build your application with debug symbols. These symbols tell gdb things like the line number upon which that particular function is defined, for example.